# Why does this break statement break not work?

Tags: java, loops, break

I have the following code:

```
public void post(String message) {
    final String mess = message;
    (new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    if (status.equals("serviceResolved")) {
                        output.println(mess);
                        Game.log.fine("The following message was successfully sent: " + mess);
                        break;
                    } else {
                        try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
                    }
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

In my log file I find a lot of lines like this:

```
The following message was successfully sent: blablabla
The following message was successfully sent: blablabla
The following message was successfully sent: blablabla
The following message was successfully sent: blablabla
```

And my program is not responding.

It seems to me that the `break` command does not work. What can be a possible reason for that.

The interesting thing is that it happens not all the time. Sometimes my program works fine, sometimes the above described problem happens.

Comment: FWIW: you could factor out the two Thread.sleep() lines into a single line executed after the outermost try/catch.

Comment: Catching of `NullPointerException` doesn't seem like a great idea (is it supposed to check whether `status == null` - if so check whether `status` is `null` instead). And `InterruptedException` should be made to break out of the loop (not that I like thread interrupt, but it is there and so should be dealt with). / Also you can make the parameter `final`, so you don't need the copy `mess`.

Comment: This is a clear reason of why you shouldn't never silent an exception unless you really need to do it: debugging becomes hell.

Comment: @Jack That and just reading the code becomes more difficult.

Comment: How is `status` declared? Is it `volatile`?

Comment: I would suspect that the post method is being called a lot, and the problem isn't local to this code. The program stops responding because it is spawning many threads (not all of which have a status of serviceResolved)

Comment: I agree with previous comments, never catch a runtime exception like you are.  However, I bet most of you people are greatly over engineering the issue of repeated logs, I think Yishai has it correct.

Comment: I would at least remove that catch on `NullPointerException`. You should never catch `RuntimeException`. They indicate code/programmer errors and should be fixed by rewriting code properly rather than by catching them. Regardless, never ignore/swallow catched exceptions, always log them.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Works fine if I change `Game.log` with `System.out`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are starting a new thread every time you call the post method. I thing the method is OK but caller program isn't.

Comment: probably should be using a queue, with a thread/executor task that is started once and reads the queue

Comment: You are kind of right. I had many lines of the message because the above given code was called many times and it was called many times because I pressed the submit button many times (when my program was frozen). And my program was frozen because of another stupid mistake which is unrelated to the given code.

Answer (score 4):

Could it be that this line succeeds:

```
output.println(mess);
```

but this line is throwing a null pointer exception:

```
Game.log.fine(...
```

In this case you'll see the output on the console, but the break statement is never reached. Is `Game.log` perhaps null?

Comment: This can't be it, because he reported seeing `The following message was successfully sent:`, which is from `Game.log` line.

Comment: Am I missing something?  The OP says that he is getting output to the log, which implies that `Game.log` can't be `null`...

Comment: I would also take it as a lesson minimize the scope of try blocks so that the catches are more meaningful.

Comment: I was assuming that 'seeing it in the log' could be interpreted loosely.

Comment: Game.log might not be null, but it might throw a NPE *after* successfully logging the statement.

Answer (score 4):

What exactly does Game.log.fine do? Could it be that it throws a NullPtrException after output, or could it be that you call the post-method several times?

Remove the catch of the NullPointerException, this is bad style (occurrence of a NullPointerException is always a programming error) and add some more log-messages in the method (or use a debugger).

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you want to keep going on a NullPointerException? If you get one inside the loop, you're likely to wait forever.

If you're sure that `status` will always eventually be `"serviceResolved"`, then put a **try...finally** inside the if statement so that if something fails, the loop still exits:

```
if (status.equals("serviceResolved")) {
    // No matter what happens next, we have to bail
    try {
        output.println(mess);
        Game.log.fine("The following message was successfully sent: " + mess);
    } finally {
        break;
    }
} else {
    try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're *assuming* that the `break` statement isn't working, but it could be that your `post` method is being called repeatedly.  Try putting another log statement at the beginning of the method to see how often it is being called.  Also, put a log statement after the `while` loop but before the end of the `run` method to verify that the `break` actually broke out of the loop.

I also agree with the other posters that catching `NullPointerException` is a code smell. You should check your variables for `null` first.