# Java ‘break’ statement sometimes not work, Why?

Tags: java, while-loop, break

I have following method:

```
public int quickFind (int[] nums, int lo, int hi) {
    if (lo >= hi)
        return -1;

    int gard = nums[lo];
    int i = lo + 1, j = hi + 1;

    while (true) {

        while (nums[++i] < gard) {
            if (i == hi) {
                System.out.println("break   " + i + " / " + hi + " ->" + (i == hi));
                break;
            }
        }

        while (gard < nums[--j]) {
            if (j == lo)
                break;
        }

        if (i > j)
            break;

        if (nums[i] == gard)
            return nums[i];
        if (nums[j] == gard) 
            return nums[j];

        int tmp = nums[i];
        nums[i] = nums[j];
        nums[j] = tmp;
    }
    nums[lo] = nums[j];
    nums[j] = gard;

    return 1 + quickFind(nums, lo, j - 1) + quickFind(nums, j + 1, hi);
}
```

And I build a random array, for instance, [3 4 2 4 1 5] to test my method. However, it seems the break statement in line 13 does not work, and throws and exception message "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6".

So, I set breakpoints to debug the break statement in line 13 and the if condition in line 11. I can't believe my eyes. The 'break' does not work.

The interesting thing is that it happens not all the time. Sometimes my program works fine, sometimes the above-described problem happens. Just like one [question that has been raised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667499/why-does-this-break-statement-break-not-work).

Who can tell me why? Why does it happen?

Comment: "I set breakpoints to debug the break statement in line 13" in the future, consider being more specific about which line. Also, you didn't tell us the values observed from that scope, especially in what combination led to unexpected behavior.

Comment: It works fine for me. When `i == hi` it goes out from the `while (nums[++i] < gard)`. Do you expect it to break also from `while (true)` ?

Comment: int[] nums = {1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5};        Random rdm = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
  
  for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
   int idx = rdm.nextInt(nums.length);
   
   int tmp = nums[idx];
   nums[idx] = nums[i];
   nums[i] = tmp;
  }    quickFind(nums, 0, nums.length-1);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An undirected `break` only breaks out of the innermost loop it appears in. For instance, the `break` here:

```
while (condition1) {
    while (condition2) {
        if (condition3) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

...breaks out of `while (condition2)` but not `while (condition1)`.

If you need to break out of an outer loop, it's probably worth doing some refactoring, but if you really need to you can *label* the outer loop and then use a directed break:

```
    outer: while (condition1) {
//  ^^^^^----- the label
        while (condition2) {
            if (condition3) {
                break outer;
// Directed ----------^^^^^
            }
        }
    }
```

That `break` will break out of both `while (condition1)` (which by definition means it breaks out of `while (condition2)`).

---

Here's a breakdown (no pun) of the `breaks` in that code and which loops they break:

```
public int quickFind (int[] nums, int lo, int hi) {
    if (lo >= hi)
        return -1;

    int gard = nums[lo];
    int i = lo + 1, j = hi + 1;

    while (true) { // *** Loop 1

        while (nums[++i] < gard) { // *** Loop 2
            if (i == hi) {
                System.out.println("break   " + i + " / " + hi + " ->" + (i == hi));
                break; // *** Breaks loop 2
            }
        }

        while (gard < nums[--j]) { // *** Loop 3
            if (j == lo)
                break; // *** Breaks loop 3
        }

        if (i > j)
            break; // *** Breaks loop 1

        if (nums[i] == gard)
            return nums[i];
        if (nums[j] == gard) 
            return nums[j];

        int tmp = nums[i];
        nums[i] = nums[j];
        nums[j] = tmp;
    }
    nums[lo] = nums[j];
    nums[j] = gard;

    return 1 + quickFind(nums, lo, j - 1) + quickFind(nums, j + 1, hi);
}
```

The function is recursive, and debugging recursive functions *can* be a bit confusing, although the recursion isn't in either of those inner loops, so I wouldn't expect it to factor in there.

Comment: The break does not break the inner loop while(condition2)!

Comment: @MonkeyDeKing: With respect, it does. If you think it doesn't, you'll need to produce a [mcve] that we can use to independently verify it, but remember the Pragmatic Progammer's advice: [`select` is not broken](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips). Neither is `break`. Perhaps the recursion is confusing you? Although it doesn't occur in the loop you're talking about...

Comment: @MonkeyDeKing if you're breaking out of the outer loop you're breaking out of the inner loop as well. And as TJ already pointed out a `break` without any mention of a label breaks the closest loop it is in, i.e. in the top snippet it _will_ break the condition2 loop while in the bottom snippet it breaks the labelled loop which is the condition1 loop.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder he might be confused by the `if (i > j) break;` so maybe you want to incorporate that into your answer

Comment: int[] nums = {3,4,2,4,1,5};       JDK1.8, Win10

Answer (score 1):

Because in some cases you are `break`ing out of the inner `while` loop, while other cases you are just `break`ing out of the outer `while` loop. Basically they are being called in different scopes.

Comment: You don't break out of an `if` statement .

Comment: ``break`` has no effect on an ``if``. It breaks out of the next surrounding loop.

Comment: I expect the break statement in line 13 to break the inner loop while(nums[++i] < gard) in line 10.

Answer (score 0):

The condition (i==hi) will not be checked when hi = 6, lo = 5, but throw OutOfBoundsException Please check their values in debugger

```
  while (nums[++i] < gard) {
        if (i == hi) {
            System.out.println("break   " + i + " / " + hi + " ->" + (i == hi));
            break;
        }
    }
```